# Get rid of foreign git branch

Tags: git, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a git project where I just have a master branch. Sometime in the past I cloned pandas somewhere in a subfolder and then deleted it. Since then I have a separate branch with plenty of pandas history. How can I get rid of it? It seems to be on a separate branch, but the branch isn't mentioned anywhere.

I tried to see if the specific commits, which I can see in sourcetree, can be assinged to a branch, but no output
`it branch --contains 58199c5da263491a26fa6cb26d2ff9d38c4b5dac`

Any suggestions how to get rid of that branch is appreciated. 
[image]

You can see above the pink branch is not from me. How can I delete it? This is my repo: https://github.com/dickreuter/poker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it a tag? `git tag -d <tagname>` would get rid of it locally. But perhaps it was someone else who created it and you got it from a fetch.

Comment: Yes that's possible, but there are plenty of tags. Is there a way to get rid of all tags?

Comment: If you mean all tags 'locally': ```git tag | xargs git tag -d```. If you mean delete tag on the remote, I would _guess_ you could push a deletion, the same way it's done with branches. If you want to delete branch blah from remote origin: ```git push origin :blah```. Perhaps it works the same way with tags.